# How to search git commit ids between given time span?

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to know the changes available in a given build id (timestamped) in Jenkins, 
and I want to search all commits id after previous build id to current build id's timestamp.

This can be an indirect way of searching the changes present in a given build id in jenkins since I am unaware of way to search the changes in the given build.

If anybody can share the way to know the new commits present in a jenkins build id, then please share it as well.

Comment: AFAIK, Jenkins puts tags for build. So what's wrong with `git log previuos-tag..current-tag` command?

Comment: Can you see a link called "Git Build Data" on each build ?

Comment: No Thong, I cannot find git build data in builds.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the two [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_limiting) options `--after` and `--before`

```
$ git log --before <current-build-timestamp> --after <previous-build-timestamp>
```